# First Google Drive App using .NET Error

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I have the error in this code..
I have taken same code from

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs#step_3_set_up_the_sample

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Util;

namespace GoogleDriveSamples
{
    class DriveCommandLineSample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";`

            // Register the authenticator and create the service
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
            var service = new DriveService(auth);

            File body = new File();
            body.Title = "My document";
            body.Description = "A test document";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
            request.Upload();

            File file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            // Get the auth URL:
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is [Here](http://pastebin.com/WQUT1qXs):

```
The best overloaded method match for
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService.DriveService(Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer) 
has some invalid arguments

Argument 1: cannot convert from
Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator<Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth.NativeApplicationClient>
to Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties:
Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringValue(System.Enum) and
Google.Apis.Util.Utilities.GetStringValue(System.Enum)
```

I also reference the needed Dll in my project.

Comment: Narrow down your question. This is not a "debug my app" forum.

Comment: var service = new DriveService(auth);  
this is my error

Comment: Start from step 1 again. "CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET" is wrong, these 2 parameters should be YOUR values...

https://developers.google.com/drive/images/clientid-secret.png

Comment: thats i know....yaaar but the error will come...
i already mention error on the Pastebin link

Comment: @HiralBhimani Leave out the the excessive "plz", and include what error you are getting in a question (questions must be self-contained, no link to some external web sites, except for non-essential reference links). And work a bit more on formatting...

Comment: @HiralBhimani I fixed your question for you a bit. Please edit it further to indicate which lines give you those errors!

Comment: Thnxxxx this line give me error ...
var service = new DriveService(auth); 

and i m new on stack overflow i try to much but i cant format it..sorry

this line give error as error are mentioned here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET client library has been recently updated, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15646014/186674 for the solution to your issue.

Comment: hey...grt yaar....thnxxx a lot it works perfect for me ...
thank u Thnak u soooo much...