# I can't compile the source code from https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs

Tags: google-drive-api

I can't compile the source code from https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs

> 1>d:\work\CSharp\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs(22,27,22,49): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService.DriveService(Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer)' has some invalid arguments
>
> 1>d:\work\CSharp\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs(22,44,22,48): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.OAuth2Authenticator' to 'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer'

These two errors referenced with `var service = new DriveService(auth);` string. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the .NET client library?

Answer (score 4):

The recently released .NET client library v1.3 beta introduced some backward-incompatible changes (http://google-api-dotnet-client.blogspot.com/2013/03/announcing-release-of-130-beta.html), the [quickstart guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) has just been updated to reflect the changes.

To fix the issue you have to replace this line:

```
var service = new DriveService(auth);
```

With the following code:

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    Authenticator = auth
});
```

You will also need to add `using Google.Apis.Services;` to your list of imports.

Comment: I cannot find any Authenticator property in the Initializer class. Why is that?

Comment: In which namespace is DriveService located?

Answer (score 0):

Ihad the same problem - https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation needs an update too ;)