# Google Drive Service in C# using xamarin OAuth

Tags: google-drive-api, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use Google Drive Service in C# using Xamarin OAuth. I can't have to find Authenticator property in DriveService constructor.
Here's my Identity Provider:

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator( Constants.ClientId,Constants.ClientSecret,
Constants.Scope, new Uri(Constants.AuthorizeUrl), new Uri(Constants.RedirectUrl),
new Uri(Constants.AccessTokenUrl));
```

I found another question on the same topic here.  However the solution didn't work for me:  I can't compile the source code from [https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15637084/i-cant-compile-the-source-code-from-https-developers-google-com-drive-quickst)

I want to call my auth in driveservice initilize:

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
???????????
});
```

Comment: That question relates back to the old .Net library I don't think you are going to get that to work at all.

Comment: so how the google services api work in xamarin      var userCredential = new UserCredential(flow, userId, token);

Comment: Have you tried looking for a more current tutorial?